# How to traverse nested array upwards from current record?

Tags: javascript

I want to traverse array from my current node to last parent node in following way :

[image]

Rules:

- Node-1 (take str from text array property from here whose str is not null and push it to currentText in parent array property)
- Node-1-1(take str from text array property from here whose str is not null and push it to currentText in parent array property)

Now what I am trying to do is for Node-1-1-1 and for currentText of Node-1-1-1 I want to traverse like this :

Node-1-1-1  ===>   Node-1-1  ====> Node-1:

```
1)  Node-1-1-1  ===>   Node-1-1

    If(Node-1-1.text[0].str !=null)
       currentText.parent.push(Node-1-1.text[0].str);
    else if(Node-1-1.text[1].str!=null)
      currentText.parent.push(Node-1-1.text[1].str);
    else 
       //do nothing

2) Node-1-1  ====> Node-1

  If(Node-1.text[0].str !=null)
       currentText.parent.push(Node-1.text[0].str);
    else if(Node-1.text[1].str!=null)
      currentText.parent.push(Node-1.text[1].str);
    else 
       //do nothing
```

So at the end for Node-1-1-1 and for currentText of Node-1-1-1,i should have output like below :

```
var currentText = 
              {
                 "str" : "This is my first Node-1-1-1 string",
                 "parent":[
                             {
                               "str" : ""This is my first Node-1 string"
                             },
                             {
                               "str" : ""This is my first Node-1-1 string"
                             }
                          ]
              }
```

**Note :** `currentNode` variable will have different node Object based on node selection.So if user selected node Node-1-1-1 then currentNode will have Node-1-1-1 object and if user selected Node-1-1 currentNode will have Node-1-1 object etc.

```js
var records = [
  {
    "name": "Node-1",
    "isParent": true,
    "text" : [
       {
           "str" : "This is my first Node-1 string",
           "parent":[]
       },
       {
          "str" : "This is my second Node-1 string",
           "parent":[]
       }],
     "nodes": [
      {
        "name": "Node-1-1",
        "isParent": false,
         "text" : [
           {
             "str" : "This is my first Node-1-1 string",
             "parent":[]
           },
           {
             "str" : "This is my second Node-1-1 string",
             "parent":[]
           }],
           "nodes": [
           {
            "name": "Node-1-1-1",
            "isParent": false,
            "text" : [
            {
              "str" : "This is my first Node-1-1-1 string",
              "parent":[]
            },
            {
              "str" : "This is my second Node-1-1-1 string",
              "parent":[]
            }],
            "nodes": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

var currentNode={
            "name": "Node-1-1-1",
            "isParent": false,
            "text" : [
            {
              "str" : "This is my first Node-1-1-1 string",
              "parent":[]
            },
            {
              "str" : "This is my second Node-1-1-1 string",
              "parent":[]
            }],
            "nodes": []
          }
var currentText = 
              {
                 "str" : "This is my first Node-1-1-1 string",
                 "parent":[]
              }

console.log(records);
```

Comment: why just only the first string of the text array of the parent node?

Comment: @NinaScholz Because i would always like to give priority to the first record of text property(if str is not null for that first record) of all parent node only(Node-1 and Node-1-1) but if it is null then take second record of text property but only if str is not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach while taking the parent node into the recusion call for getting the wanted strings.

Basically it iterates the actual array and checks if a parent is given from the call.

If given, then the parent property gets an update with the parent's parent items and with the direct parent.

If another `node` exist, then the function is called again with the `node` propery and the actual node as parent.

```js
function setParent(array, parent) {
    array.forEach(function (o) {
        parent && o.text.forEach(function (p) {
            p.parent = p.parent.concat(parent.text[0].parent);
            p.parent.push({ str: parent.text[0].str });
        });
        o.nodes && setParent(o.nodes, o);
    });
}

var data = [{ name: "Node-1", isParent: true, text: [{ str: "This is my first Node-1 string", parent: [] }, { str: "This is my second Node-1 string", parent: [] }], nodes: [{ name: "Node-1-1", isParent: false, text: [{ str: "This is my first Node-1-1 string", parent: [] }, { str: "This is my second Node-1-1 string", parent: [] }], nodes: [{ name: "Node-1-1-1", isParent: false, text: [{ str: "This is my first Node-1-1-1 string", parent: [] }, { str: "This is my second Node-1-1-1 string", parent: [] }], nodes: [] }] }] }];

setParent(data);

document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, 0, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

With a given name of a node, you could use an iterative and recursive approach as well for searching after a fiven node name and retuning all parent node information.

```js
function getString(array) {
    var string;
    return array.some(function (o) {
        return string = o.str;
    }) && string || '';
}

function getParent(array, node, parents) {
    var result;
    return array.some(function (o) {
        if (o.name === node) {
            result = parents;
            return true;
        }
        return o.nodes && (result = getParent(o.nodes, node, (parents || []).concat(getString(o.text))));
    }) && result || undefined;
}

var data = [{ name: "Node-1", isParent: true, text: [{ str: "This is my first Node-1 string", parent: [] }, { str: "This is my second Node-1 string", parent: [] }], nodes: [{ name: "Node-1-1", isParent: false, text: [{ str: "This is my first Node-1-1 string", parent: [] }, { str: "This is my second Node-1-1 string", parent: [] }], nodes: [{ name: "Node-1-1-1", isParent: false, text: [{ str: "This is my first Node-1-1-1 string", parent: [] }, { str: "This is my second Node-1-1-1 string", parent: [] }], nodes: [] }] }] }];

console.log(getParent(data, 'foo'));
console.log(getParent(data, 'Node-1'));
console.log(getParent(data, 'Node-1-1'));
console.log(getParent(data, 'Node-1-1-1'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This worked.Thank you so much for your kind efforts towards helping me.Appreciated :)